# Lagrange interpolation error depended on number of nodes

Tags: c, numerical-methods

My task is to calculate estimation of error in the dependence of the number of nodes (n). As an estimation of the norm of error i have to calculate the maximum modul of difference in the set of points t=j/M   (j=1...M),where M is relatively big number.I wrote a programm,but i'm not sure why this estimation is correct.Or maybe it isn't?

(In the programm f(x)=sin(x),but it might be any other function)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
double func(double x) 
 {
    return sin(x) ; 
 }
double lagr(double *x,double *f,double t,int n) ; 
int main(void)
{
     int n,k,M=100000 ; 
     double *x,*f,t,maxr=0,L,a=0,b=1 ; 
  printf("n=") ; scanf("%d",&n) ; 
  x=(double*)malloc(n*sizeof(double));
  f=(double*)malloc(n*sizeof(double));
 /*printf("a=") ; scanf("%le",&a) ; 
   printf("b=") ; scanf("%le",&b) ; */
   
   x[0]=a ; x[n-1]=b; 
     for(k=1;k<n-1;k++)
     {
          x[k]=a+((b-a)*k)/n ; f[k]=func(x[k]) ; 
     }  
       for(k=0 ; k<M ; k++) 
     {
         t=(double) k/M ;
         L=lagr(x,f,t,n)  ; 
         if(fabs(L-func(t))>maxr) maxr=fabs(L-func(t)) ; 
     }  
     printf("Error estimation=%le",maxr) ; 
     return 0 ;
}

double lagr(double *x,double *f,double t,int n)
{
   int k,j;
   double sum=0,p;
   
   for(k=0;k<n;k++)
      {
       p=1 ;
       for(j=0 ; j<n ; j++)
       {
         if(j!=k)
          {
           p*=(t-x[j])/(x[k]-x[j]) ; 
          }    
       }
       sum+=p*f[k] ; 
     }
return sum ; 
}
```

Comment: Your code contains errors: You allocate memory using `malloc` based on an undefined value of `n` before you ask for the input. This results in a memory access error. I suggest to add a trailing newline in `printf("Error estimation=%le\n",maxr) ;` It is difficult to find out if the output of your code is correct or not if the program is not sufficiently documented by using *meaningful* variable names and comments. (I don't mean to explain the obvious, e.g. that `p=1 ;` sets `p` to the vaule of 1, but what's the purpose/meaning of `p` and why do you set it to 1 (and not e.g. 0 or 2).

Comment: Why do you think the result might be incorrect? You are aware of the Runge example? /// You might want to explore the effect of catastrophic cancellation, that is, check the size of the Lagrange kernels relative to the exact result. If the difference of two values in the range 1e12 has size 1, then the remaining accuracy is 4 decimal digits.

Comment: @Bodo you're right.Didn't notice i was using malloc before input of n.I'm using p to calculate (x-xi)(xk-xi) for all i and k.This is because p=1

Comment: @LutzLehmann i didn't know about Runge phenomenon.I should read about it.Thanks

Comment: @LutzLehmann i read about it.But still don't understand why do we take t=j/M and why this estimation will be correct.Maybe you could explain it?

Comment: M is just a "very large" number, so that the sampling points are dense in the interval. I think the difference to the true maximal error is O(1/M^2), which is a rather small bound for this M.